# ZED SDK error while loading shared libraries: libGLEW.so.1.13: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I'm trying to run the ZED Explorer application from ZED SDK. But when I do that, I get this error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libGLEW.so.1.13: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried to fix it using the other solutions mentioned on SO but didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your software needs the GLEW library, and you're missing the shared library libGLEW.so.1.13, so you have to install it. 
Looking for it through aptitude or apt-cache:

```
sudo apt-cache search libGLEW
```

shows that it belongs to the GLEW library.
So install the library through:

```
sudo apt-get install glew-utils
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your answer. However, I tried doing what you told me, I still get the same error

"error while loading shared libraries: libGLEW.so.1.13: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: Ok, so we assume that you already have the library: execute "sudo find / -name libGLEW.so.1.13 -type f", it should return its path like something/lib. When you get the path, copy and paste it in /etc/ld.so.conf. Then run "sudo ldconfig".